# Web-site where I could post my java-code and get a help on its compilation

Tags: java, web-services

Is there any web-site where I could post my java-code (not very long, around A4, Arial 10) and get a help on it? The thing is that one of the functions does not work in the way I need, and debugging does not help me to solve the problem. As far as I understand it´s not good idea to post the code here.

**Edit#1**
This web-site should also provide opportunities to ask buddies to optimize the existing code.

Comment: Here is OK. But a debugger won't help you if the code doesn't even compile. Show us the code and the compiler error messages.

Comment: Sorry, the code is compiled. But one of the functions does not work in the proper way. It should be changed, but I don´t know how to do this. Also, my solution might be not the most optimal.

Comment: *"As far as I understand it´s not good idea to post the code here."*  Whatever makes you think that?  I cannot recall anyone complaining when someone posts an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) *"This web-site should also provide opportunities to ask buddies to optimize the existing code."* While not specifically about optimization, you might check out http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shrink down your problem case to a manageable size. Get rid of unnecessary code. Leave only enough to reproduce the problem and definitely post it here. There are plenty of folks who will review your code.